# Convert dict to string

Tags: string, dictionary, python-2.7

Have been searching how to convert a dictionary to a string. But the results found is not the ones i am looking for.
The results i currently find is basically turning the whole dictionary into a string, but i don't really want {}, , and : in my string.
So i got a dictionary of sorted URLvars i wanted to join together again.

```
vars = {"id":"2", "test":"3"}
```

so i want a way to convert this dictionary to:

```
vars = "id=2&test=3"
```

**UPDATE:**
Thanks for the help. Here is also the POC i made for the larger script i am doing! Might be better ways to write this tho ;P

```
from urlparse import urlparse
import urllib

def main(url, var, params):
    urllenght = len(url)
    urlfind = url.find("?")
    lenght = urlfind - urllenght

    params = '&'.join(["%s=%s" % (k, v) for k, v in params.iteritems()])
    url = url[:lenght]

    print params
    print url
    print url+"?"+params

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url="http://test.com/index.php?id=2&test=2"
    url2 = urlparse(url)
    params = dict([part.split('=') for part in url2[4].split('&')])
    print "Avaible URL params"
    for k,v in params.items():
        print "Params: %s" % k

    while True:
        var = raw_input("Select param: ")
        if var in params:
            main(url, var, params)
            break
        else:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need, is [`urllib.urlencode`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode):

```
>>> import urllib
>>> vars = {"id":"2", "test":"3"}
>>> urllib.urlencode(vars)
test=3&id=2
```

But keep in mind, that it will also convert special URL symbols to their %-form. So, if you don't want that, try simply:

```
'&'.join([`%s=%s` % (k, v) for k, v in vars.iteritems()])
```

Comment: Argh. Been looking up and down the urllib section. Didn't think of using urlencode that way.
Thanks!

Comment: @user1299507 you might want to [accept the helpful answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).